# sign in/out views for iOS authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, restkit

I'm new to iOS programming. Wondering if anyone can point me to a sample project that includes the views and logic for the user sign in/sign out process. Ultimately I plan to use the [Restkit](http://restkit.org/) library, but I could use some help acquiring the user name and password necessary for doing the HTTP basic auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking for is just a way to prompt a user for a username and password for some arbitrary service, check out `UIAlertView`, specifically with the `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput` style (new to iOS5).

If not, well maybe you can describe the "user sign in/sign out process" you're looking for in a little more detail? As far as I know, there's no such thing. iOS doesn't support multiple users, so there's no username or login on the OS level. On the application level, there is App Store login (for purchases with an AppleID) and iCloud login behavior, but applications never have access to the usernames or passwords involved.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, @jemmons. `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput` sounds useful.